# Disable button if checkbox is checked and label is a specific text

Tags: javascript, jsp, event-handling

I have a table with a datagrid (checkboxes and labels in each row). I want to disable a button by checking if a label is "Forbidden". The user can check multiple checkboxes. So my question is how do I get all the checked checkboxes and then check if the label in each selected row is of value "Forbidden" so I can disable the button.

I tried something like this:

```
$(function() {
    checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id=checkId]');
    var validateBtn = $('button[name="btnVal"]');
    checkboxes.forEach((cb) => {
        cb.addEventListener('change', checkStatus);
    });
    function checkStatus() {
        //to-do
        // if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            
            var label = document.getElementById('statusLabel');
            if (label.textContent == "Forbidden") {
                validateBtn.prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    });
```

The table looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZhHW.png) In this case the button should be disabled as we have selected a forbidden status.

Comment: Post html code in question.

Comment: try this code `validateBtn.attr("disabled", true) `

Comment: its a documentum/jsp project but i will post it

Comment: `checkboxes =`? Don't bloat the `Window` scope. Use `const checkboxes =` Why are you mixing jQuery and vanilla JS? If you already use jQuery - use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the property of the checkbox and disable the button according to this will be:

```
$('#id_of_your_checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#id_of_your_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#id_of_your_button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```